# nodemon multiple script not running

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, nodemon

Hi is there any way to run multiple script in series using nodemon

i essentially trying to do

**ng build // angular build**

then

**node server.js**

i try using npmm scripts

like

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng build || node server",
 }
```

> npm run start  ## run fine

but if i

> nodemon run start  --inspect

but it either run only one command or run both at the same time

Comment: probably you need to do `and` something like this: `"ng build && node server"`

Comment: is Angular source is in another directory other than root?

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty ng build && node server does run in parallel

Comment: @ChauTran both in the same root